PyQt6 QSS Style Sheet with Embedded SVG
I am working on putting together a QSS Stylesheet template that I can use for all of my PyQt6 applications. When I use the stylesheet to modify the style of a QComboBox, I lose the down arrow. It's my understanding that if I style one part of the combo box, I have to style the whole combo box, which isn't a problem.
In my stylesheet template, I use flags like background-color: @widget-background;. I then have a separate files for each color theme (i.e. light & dark) with a corresponding entry of @widget-background = #777777 for a light gray color. At runtime I simply read in the template as a sting and perform a replace for each of the color tags. This works awesome and makes it easy to add color themes without recreating the entire stylesheet.
Where I am having my problem is with the down-arrow sub-element of the QComboBox. I know that I can supply a PNG or SVG image in the stylesheet, which works reasonably well. But, it's not as elegant as I would like. First of all, I have to create a separate image file for each color theme. Second, I have to open the SVG file as a text file and manually change the colors (Yes, I know I could automate this). So, what I would like to do is embed the SVG content into the stylesheet directly. It's my understanding that this is possible and I have found an example on StackOverflow (Inline SVG in CSS).
Based on that solution, I've put together the following basic application with a single QComboBox with it's stylesheet applied.
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class ComboBoxTest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Create a QComboBox
        combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        combo_box.addItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])

        # Minimal stylesheet with embedded SVG for down arrow
        combo_box.setStyleSheet("""
            QComboBox {
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                color: #000000;
                border: 1px solid #0078d4;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            QComboBox::drop-down {
                background-color: #dcdcdc;
                border: none;
                width: 20px;
                border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
            }
            QComboBox::down-arrow {
                image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16'><path style='fill:%23dddddd;stroke:%23ff0000;' d='M 1,4 15,4 8,12 Z'/></svg>");
            }
        """)

        # Layout to hold the combo box
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(combo_box)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('QComboBox SVG Test')
        self.resize(300, 100)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ComboBoxTest()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

When I run this using Python 3.11 and PyQt6, the arrow doesn't show up. Do you see anything wrong? Does this code work properly for you? Do you have any other ideas of how I can go about this, preferably entirely in my stylesheet?
I appreciate any help you can give me.

QSS are only based on CSS, they don't support the full specification. In fact, they fundamentally follow just the basic concepts and syntax of CSS2.1 (with some custom properties/attributes) and almost nothing of CSS3, therefore, they do not support inline/embedded contents (not even using base64). The url property can only be a path corresponding to a physical file in the system or in the Qt resource system. Check the syntax and reference docs, if you don't see something there, it's not supported.

Thanks for the quick feedback @musicamante. It's a bummer that the functionality is limited that way. I created a work around that suits my needs by creating a template SVG file with the same tags as the stylesheet. I then just watch for the appropriate tag to modify the down-arrow color, use the color to modify the SVG and save to a temp file, then add the path to the temp file to the stylesheet. I did have to modify my python code for this (which I was trying to avoid), but it didn't take much and I have the functionality I was looking for.

I understand the frustration, as the possibility of using embedded/inline images would certainly useful, and an unresolved feature suggestion has been submitted years ago (QTBUG-51081, somebody commented that they were able to make it work with background-image but I haven't been able to reproduce it). Yet, consider that QSS are meant to be fast, they can possibly have to be parsed multiple times: they are inherited by parents and rules are "accumulated", meaning that any new child possibly requires computation of the whole "QSS tree", including »

» properties that may require further computation, especially if the properties may affect geometry requirements. Adding the base64 feature (detecting, decoding, validation) would most probably increase the overhead of an already delicate mechanism that should always be as fast as possible under any circumstance (you may have a relatively static UI, but the styling API cannot make that assumption), therefore I can understand the reasoning behind not implementing that possibility. Note that if you want to provide advanced customization, you may consider switching to a QProxyStyle instead. »

» It has the major benefit of allowing complete control over any styling aspect, but it comes with two major drawbacks: 1. you obviously need to do the whole style implementation by code, losing the convenience of style sheets syntax; 2. it's almost completely incompatible with QSS, as any widget affected by even just one QSS rule would have a private QStyleSheetStyle that completely overrides the proxy style. If you're not experienced with QStyle, dynamically creating those images is the only acceptable solution.
